# meaning of the phrase "all out rip doing someone"?

Tags: meaning, slang

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/VKDD_HUWywQ). It is at around 31 second. Here is the context:

> You might be surprised by the end of the video because I am not going to come out here and **all out rip** keto dieting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rip** refers to speaking about something in a critical and negative light.

The "**all out**" prefix means "without holding back" or "full force."

So in the case of your example, the statement could be rephrased as:

> You might be surprised by the end of the video because I am not going to come out here and {relentlessly and harshly criticize} keto dieting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of a couple phrases that need to be interpreted separately:

- [**all-out**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-out) : completely; with full force or determination
- [**rip**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rip) : to criticize or disparage

So you might paraphrase it as "I am not going to **completely disparage** keto dieting."